# how to create a chrome extension in visual studio that interacts with my web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, google-chrome-extension, serial-port

I want to create a google chrome extension for serial port listener which will send the weight to my web application.
I Have seen a chrome extension Browser Serial Port Monitor which is working fine.
But I want that weight to use in my web application...

???
Any Idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, the [Serial Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/serial-monitor/ohncdkkhephpakbbecnkclhjkmbjnmlo) is Chrome Apps, not Chrome Extensions. [The API to read from/write to Serial Port](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_serial) is provided for Chrome Apps only. Thus, you need to create your Chrome App to communicate with Serial Port and to read the weight. Also, if you want to send the weight read by the Chrome App to your Web application, you may send it with Ajax described at [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external).